How to load and query json data to use as input parameter
Is it possible to load a json file (scoped to a job) that looks like this:
{
  "first-api": {
    "subscriptionId": {
      "dev": "1234",
      "test": "5678",
    }
  }
}

and use it kind of like:
- template: 'templates/deploySomething.yml'
  parameters:
    subscriptionId: loadedJsonData.[parameters.api].subscriptionId.[parameters.stage]

thank you in advance

Did my answer help?

hi @RuiJarimba,
thank you for your answer.
i solved this differently... i just loaded all data and use a filter to get what i need.

@heycaptain Tried Ruj's solution and it worked fine. If you have other solutions, it's better to post it with detailed steps here, this can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

I'm afraid what you're trying to do is not possible in Azure pipelines.
You can do instead:

Parse the json file in a script task and set a pipeline variable
Pass the pipeline variable to the template as a parameter

Example
Considering json file $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/json-data.json:
{
  "first-api": {
    "subscriptionId": {
      "dev": "1234",
      "test": "5678"
    }
  }
}

The following pipeline parses the json file and extracts the subscription ID based on the selected API name and environment:
name: json_parse_$(Date:yyMMdd)$(Rev:rr)

parameters:
  - name: apiName
    displayName: API Name
    type: string
    default: 'first-api'

  - name: environment
    displayName: Environment
    type: string
    default: 'dev'
    values:
      - 'dev'
      - 'test'

trigger: none

variables:
  - name: jsonFilePath
    value: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/json-data.json'
  - name: jsonPath
    value: '."${{ parameters.apiName }}".subscriptionId.${{ parameters.environment }}'

steps:
  - checkout: self

  - script: |
      ENVIRONMENT='${{ parameters.environment }}'
      JSON_FILE_PATH='${{ variables.jsonFilePath }}'
      JSON_PATH='${{ variables.jsonPath }}'

      # Debug: Print the actual jq command to be executed
      echo "jq command: jq -r \"$JSON_PATH\" \"$JSON_FILE_PATH\""

      # Use jq to extract the subscription ID for the given environment
      SUBSCRIPTION_ID=$(jq -r "$JSON_PATH" "$JSON_FILE_PATH")

      echo "Subscription ID for $ENVIRONMENT environment: $SUBSCRIPTION_ID"

      echo "Creating pipeline variable SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=SUBSCRIPTION_ID]$SUBSCRIPTION_ID"
    displayName: Parse environment subscription ID
  
  - template: /pipelines/steps/do-something-steps.yaml
    parameters:
      subscriptionId: $(SUBSCRIPTION_ID)

Running the pipeline:

Please note that in order to access a property with a hyphen (-) in its name using jq, you should use syntax ."property-name":
jq -r '."first-api".subscriptionId.dev' json-data.json

